# Symbol denoting "for at least one"

Tags: notation

As a lazy mathematician, I'm tired of having to write "for at least one". Similar to the $\forall$ (for all) symbol, does a symbol exist to denote "for at least one"? I've been abbreviating to f.a.l.o., but I was hoping for some more elegant notation.

Comment: I have seen many people write "f.s. $x$" to mean "for some $x$."

Comment: Yes indeed, it is the following $\exists(x)$ (there exist(s) x).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The **existential quantifier** "$\exists x.\phi(x)$" in formal logic denotes "there exists at least one $x$ that satisfies the property $\phi(x)$".

If you're not writing very formally symbolic logic, you should also consider sticking to English, but just writing "some" instead of "at least one", as in

> Now, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $p(z)=0$ for some $z$. ...

since "at least one" *is* the conventional mathematical meaning of "some"+singular noun. With this wording you're even allowed to *keep* referring to the $z$ that makes $p(z)=0$ in the following sentences you write, whereas the $z$ in $\exists z.p(z)=0$ goes out of scope at the end of the formula.

Note that whereas one occasionally sees people abbreviate, for example, "$f(x)>0$ for all $x$" as "$f(x)>0 ~\forall x$", this heinous abuse of symbolism is rare for the existential quantifier. Properly used, quantifiers are always written *before* the formula they control:
$$ \forall x.f(x)>0 $$
$$ \exists z.p(z)=0 $$
and so forth. Several [minor variations in punctuation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79190/different-standards-for-writing-down-expressions-in-a-formal-way/79209#79209) exist, such as
$$ (\forall x)\, f(x)>0 $$
$$ \forall x(\,f(x)>0\,) $$

Comment: Fantastic answer which not only addressed my question but expanded my knowledge on more general mathematical notation. Thank you very much! I had stumbled upon the $\exists$ symbol, but I wasn't sure whether it implied the existence of a unique object, of multiple objects, or of at least one object. This clears that up. *****

Comment: Follow-up question: how could I use the $\exists$ symbol in the following sense: $f(A_0)=\{b\mid b=f(a)$ **for at least one** $ a \in A_0\}$?

Comment: The existence of a _unique_ object is often notated with an exclamation sign combined with $\exists$, as in $\exists_! x.\phi(x)$. Though very useful, it is not taught quite as often as the ordinary $\forall$ and $\exists$ -- and then usually as an abbreviation for asserting existence and uniqueness separately: $$\exists_! x.\phi(x) \text{ means }(\exists x.\phi(x)\land \forall x.\forall y.(\phi(x)\land\phi(y)\to x=y)$$.

Comment: @lodhb: Follow-up answer: You don't. If you want to put the specification of $a$ _after_ the property it satisfies, you need to use English (or a natural language of your choice), not symbols.

Comment: OK, thanks. What a pity though, having to write words ;-) I suggest we start our own standards, what do you say? :-P

Comment: What’s wrong with $f(A_0) = \{ b \mid \exists a \in A_0.b = f(a) \}$?

Comment: Or, since the $b$ serves no purpose: $f(A_0) = \{f(a) : a\in A_0\}$

Comment: @lodhb: I may have misread the intention behind the follow-up question. It would have been more helpful to include something like Konrad's response.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I've read, it sounds like there is no standard abbreviation of "for at least one" or "for some", but what I typically use to denote "for some" in my own personal notes is the inverted F: $\Finv$ (LaTeX `\Finv`)

It felt like a natural fit since it resembles the existential symbol $\exists$ (whose meaning it shares) just with the top line removed, and "F" is the first sound in the phrase "for some". I commonly use it when I wish to put an existential quantifier *after* what it quantifies over (improper as it may be), e.g.
$$ x+1 = 2 \quad \Finv\ x $$
I considered using $\exists$ for this purpose, but that felt awkward since "for some" has no initial "E" sound, and it would be confusing to have to remember to read $\exists$ as "for some" only when it is placed after a formula.

Comment: I like this very much