# Value of an expression with an impossible predicate

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, integers

let $a = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n)^T$ for some arbitrary large (irrelevant to the question) value of $n$.

and let $i,k \in \mathbb{Z}$

What would the value of the following expression be when $i = 0$?

$$\forall k : 0 < k < i: a_{k-1} \le a_k$$

As $i$ and $k$ are integers, there is no k such that $0 < k < i$. Does that mean that the entire expression is true because it holds "for all" (zero) admissible values of $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Terminlogy alert: it is not an "expression" but a "formula" -- it can be true or false, but doesn't have a "value").

It is an abbreviation for

$$ \forall k :\quad 0<k<i \implies a_{k-1} \le a_k $$

When $i=0$, then no matter what you choose for $k$, the antecedent $0<k<i$ will be false, and "$\mathsf{false}\Rightarrow\mathit{whatever}$" is always *true*, so the entire thing behind the $\forall k$ is always true. And that makes the entire formula true.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on terminology. I'm (evidently) a CS-student.

Comment: @thwd: I guessed as much -- programming languages rarely bother to make a distinction between Boolean expressions and other ones, and seem to do fine without one -- but for better or worse, the tradition in mathematics is to distinguish them syntactically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.   $$\forall k\in S: P (k)$$

is an abbreviation for

$$\forall k:k\in S \implies P (k)$$

so when $S$ is empty,  as it is here, the left side of the implication is false and the entire implication is true.

Comment: This might be a stupid detail but in my case it's a colon, not a period as in your answer. Does that make any difference? Also, I'm sorry for the wrong terminology used in the question.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.  Sorry for my needlessly confusing variation!

Comment: @thwd: Each author seems to have his own preferences for which punctuation to use with quantifiers, and _in general_ it doesn't make any difference. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79190/different-standards-for-writing-down-expressions-in-a-formal-way/79209#79209) for an attempt at surveying the options.