# What is the correct way to write in first-order formula that for any natural number $n$, $P(n)$ is true?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I haven't learned first-order logic in a systematic way.

**Question.** What is the correct way to write in first-order formulas correctly the following statement?

> For any natural number $n$, $P(n)$ is true.

---

Two candidate I come up with are the following:

- $\forall n$ $(n\in{\bf N}\to P(n))$
- $\forall (n\in{\bf N})P(n)$

The second one can not be right according to the instruction in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Semantics) Wikipedia article. However, it is also used in [another article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Axiom_of_induction).

Comment: First-order set theory, or first-order arithmetic?

Comment: See [Different standards for writing down logical quantifiers in a formal way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79190/different-standards-for-writing-down-logical-quantifiers-in-a-formal-way).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: thanks for the reference!