# Which is the difference between the logical propositions $\exists a, b$ and $\exists a \exists b$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I was wondering if there is any difference between $\exists a,b$ and $\exists a \exists b$. I can't imagine there would be any but my homework uses them both.

Comment: In my opinion, they are not different...

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: This question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323172). I only know about the linked question though because I answered it; there may be a canonical duplicate that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former abbreviates the latter, just as $$\exists x{\in}\mathbb R\;Px$$ abbreviates $$\exists x\,\big(x{\in}\mathbb R\land Px\big),$$ and $$\forall\;a,b$$ abbreviates $$∀a\,∀b.$$